# Unable to Refresh View When going back in NavigationView with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift5

I have navigation view that shows the details of a Department object. Within the Department, there are several Groups and within each Group there are a number of Teams. All these different objects are within their own views using a navigation view. I have a viewModel that publishes the changes which is observed in the Views. The problem I am having is that when I update the Team with a new set of members and when I go back to see if the updates are reflected in the Group view and I don't see them. I need to go up one more level to the Department view and go the Group View to see the changes. Basically, the refresh is triggered when go up one more level and come back into the Group View. I thought that updating the Group view when the Team members are updated would automatically trigger the view refresh. I can see that the values have changed in the debugger, but the view is not refreshed. What am I missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below are relevant part of the code:

Department Model

```
class Department: Object {
    let groups = List<Group>()
    @objc dynamic var name: String? = "department"
    @objc dynamic var employees: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var availableHours: Double = 0.0
    
    @objc private dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.employees = groups.map(\.employees).reduce(0, +)
        self.availableHours = groups.map(\.availableHours).reduce(0, +)
    }
    
    func update() {
        self.employees = groups.map({$0.employees}).reduce(0, +)
        self.availableHours = groups.map(\.availableHours).reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

Group Model class. Group has Department as Parent and Teams as children

```
class Group: Object, Identifiable {
    let teams = List<Team>()
    @objc dynamic var department: Department?
    @objc dynamic var name: String? = "group"
    @objc dynamic var employees: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var availableHours: Double = 0
    
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    convenience init(department: Department, name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.department = department
        self.name = name
        
        self.employees = teams.map({$0.size}).reduce(0, +)
        self.availableHours = teams.map(\.hoursAvailable).reduce(0, +)
    }
    
    func update() {
        self.employees = teams.map({$0.size}).reduce(0, +)
        self.availableHours = teams.map(\.hoursAvailable).reduce(0, +)
        department?.update()
    }
    
    func addTeam(team: Team) {
        teams.append(team)
        department?.update()
    }
}
```

Teams class

```
class Team: Object, Identifiable {
    @objc dynamic var name: String? = "team"
    @objc dynamic var group: Group?
    @objc dynamic var size: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var hoursAvailable: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    convenience init(group: Group, name: String, size: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.group = group
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.hoursAvailable = Double(size) * 8.0
    }
    
    func addMembers(size: Int) {
        self.size += size
        hoursAvailable += 8.0 * Double(size)
        group?.update()
    }
}
```

The Views:

```
struct DepartmentView: View {
    var department: Department?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Total Employees")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(department!.employees)")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Total Groups")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(department!.groups.count)")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Total Hours")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(department!.availableHours)")
                }
                
                ForEach(department!.groups) { g in
                    NavigationLink(destination: GroupView(groupvm: GroupVM(group: g))) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Employees")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(g.employees)")
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("Available Hours")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(g.availableHours)")
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("Teams")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(g.teams.count)")
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(department!.name!)
        }
    }
}
```

Team ViewModel

```
class TeamVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var teamdb: Team
    
    init(team: Team) {
        self.teamdb = team
    }
    
    var team: Team {
        teamdb
    }
    
    func updateMembers(size: Int) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            try realm.write() {
                teamdb.addMembers(size: size)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your model is reference-type (classes), so when you update model objects the references to them are not changed in parent holder. To have automatic refresh you have to make all them value-type, ie. structs, or, if it is not applicable, to push refresh manually by call `.objectWillChange.send()` on `ObservableObject` instance.

Comment: I have Realm Objects, therefore, I put objectWillChange.send() on the ObservableObjects but it does not fix the problem. The Parent View refresh when I navigate back is not triggered

Comment: @Asperi, here is what I ended up doing, I added the .objectWillChange.send() within the .onAppear() and it worked. However, I am not sure, if I am doing the right thing. This could be inefficient as .onAppear() is getting called always. Is there a better way or is there a way to call this only when the back button is pressed.